# LUA: How to get the value of a table item whose name is contained in a string

Tags: arrays, string, lua

I have the following information in LUA:

```
local a = "myTable.elem2.sub2";

myTable = {
   ["elem1"] = {
      ["sub1"] = "abc",
      ["sub2"] = "def",
      ["sub3"] = "ghi",     
   },
   ["elem2"] = {
      ["sub1"] = "jkl",
      ["sub2"] = "mno",
      ["sub3"] = "pqr",     
   },

}
```

Considering that there could be many structures and I don't know the fields of these, how can I get the value of the field whose name is contained in the variable "a"?

I need to get "mno"

local b = something

I've tried splitting "a" into an array, but how do I put the information back together to then get the value of the element I want?

Comment: `local b = assert((loadstring or load)("return "..a))()`

Comment: split it, then for each split, traverse it using a temporary pointer

Comment: @ESkri I forgot to mention I can't use **load** or **loadstring**,

Comment: @Xarxus - Why ?

Comment: @ESkry cause it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```lua
local myTable = {
    ["elem1"] = {
        ["sub1"] = "abc",
        ["sub2"] = "def",
        ["sub3"] = "ghi",
    },
    ["elem2"] = {
        ["sub1"] = "jkl",
        ["sub2"] = "mno",
        ["sub3"] = "pqr",
    },
}

local a = myTable["elem2"]["sub2"]
print(a)
local b = myTable.elem2.sub2
print(b)
```

Comment: Nope, what I need is a function that I can pass a string with the name of the field whose value I want. The function should return the value I want.
I forgot to mention that I can't use **load**.

Answer (score 0):

The **load** function is convenient to solve your problem, however we should avoid using this dangerous function in our code.

Here is an equivalent for `load("return " .. a)()`, hope it helps.

Note: Only works when `myTable` is a global table, not local.

```lua
local function getValueByKeyName(str)
  -- you can find the code of string:split at 
  --  http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=u108/split
  local splitted = str:split("%.")

  -- _G is the table that stores global variables
  -- We can use _G to access a global table with its name
  local t = _G[splitted[1]]

  -- Then, traverse the splitted array to get the value
  -- and store the value in t
  for i, v in ipairs(splitted) do
    if type(t) ~= "table" then return nil end
    if i ~= 1 then -- splitted[1] is used by _G
      t = t[v]
    end
  end

  -- Finally, return the value. If there is any error in str
  -- this function will return nil instead.
  return t
end

-- Output: myTable.elem2.sub2=mno
print(a .. "=" .. getValueByKeyName(a))
```